# How can 'names' attribute have the same length of the vector?

Tags: r, vector, names

```
full2=glmmTMB(feedp~reprosex+foodav+rainfall+temp+(1|scan)
             +(1+reprosex.pregnant+reprosex.earlylac+reprosex.latelac+reprosex.male||ID),
             data=t.data, family=beta_family(link="logit"),
             control=glmmTMBControl(optimizer=optim, optArgs=list(method="BFGS")))
```

```
Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

I was trying to run the model(full2), but I got this error message.
How can I have the same length?

My data looks like this.

```
> str(t.data)
'data.frame':   3058 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ feedp            : num  0.222 0.2 0.273 0.444 0.235 ...
 $ reprosex         : Factor w/ 5 levels "cycling","earlylac",..: 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 ...
 $ foodav           : int  210 210 210 210 210 210 210 210 210 210 ...
 $ rainfall         : num  2.6 2.6 0 106.1 33.6 ...
 $ temp             : num  22.3 22.3 23.9 24.1 24.1 ...
 $ ID               : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","S": 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ scan             : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ reprosex.earlylac: num  -0.107 -0.107 -0.107 -0.107 -0.107 ...
 $ reprosex.latelac : num  -0.105 -0.105 -0.105 -0.105 -0.105 ...
 $ reprosex.male    : num  0.498 -0.502 0.498 -0.502 0.498 ...
 $ reprosex.pregnant: num  -0.0752 -0.0752 -0.0752 -0.0752 -0.0752 ...
```

```
> names(t.data)
 [1] "feedp"             "reprosex"          "foodav"           
 [4] "rainfall"          "temp"              "ID"               
 [7] "scan"              "reprosex.earlylac" "reprosex.latelac" 
[10] "reprosex.male"     "reprosex.pregnant"
> length(t.data$ID)
[1] 3058
> length(vector)
[1] 1
```

For solving this problem, I tried to update R version and I checked the length of attribut [6] and the vector. But I couldn't find way...

Please tell me, if you need more information about my data to give the answer. Thank you.